# AppStore rejects SandBox of MacOS app with externally built console binaries

Tags: macos, app-store, executable, codesign, appstore-sandbox

I have 2 MacOS apps I want to submit to appstore. One is pretty much a GUI for a console program; the other is application on its own, but does heavy usage of another console program.

Both these console program binaries are open source, MIT licensed, but have very external and specific build environments (including cmake and etc) and would be unnecessary (and a pain) to integrate them to building together with my apps. So I would like to build them, then embed them in its respectively applications.

I got them embedded, and tested with app sandbox enabled. Everything works fine. However, when I try to submit to Apple Store, they claim something like this:

**ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "MWAPPTECH.MyApp.pkg/Payload/TheHider.app/Contents/Resources/myConsoleBinary" )] Refer to App Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/ for more information on sandboxing your app."**

*"https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/" doesn't appear to exist...*

According to my research, It appears I have to codesign these console executables somehow. I tried to codesign the executables myself, but it resulted in utter failure.

I am completely lost in this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1). Yes, you have to sign and enable sandbox restrictions for all binaries in your bundle. Otherwise sandboxing makes no sense if an app could circumvent it with a helper binary.

Comment: *resulted in utter failure* isn't descriptive in a way that will help us help you. What did you do, specifically? What happened when you did it?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was embedding Perl: this simple codesign command added the proper entitlement and the upload worked afterwards:

codesign -v -f --sign "Developer ID Application: BlahBlah" --entitlements staticPerl.entitlements $perlEmbedRoot/bin/staticPerl5.30.0

Where the entitlements file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My externally built console binary just happens to be a static perl, but any command line program would be signed this way.  Other than being static, it’s a normal perl build using Configure/make, and the result is an executable and a library of support code.  I do not build this in Xcode, it’s done once, outside of Xcode. I simply copy the executable and (a pruned) lib/* to a folder named “perlembed", then codesign perl with its entitlements.  That folder “perlembed” is added to my Xcode project and is part of the App’s target and appears as a resource in the Resources folder of the App package.  There is nothing special at all about the folder tree, but here it is (excluding lib/* which isn’t relevant anyway).  HTH:

```
cd ~/Private/Developer/staticPerl/
./buildStaticPerl
cp staticPerl5.30.0 $perlEmbedRoot/bin/
codesign -v -f --sign "Developer ID Application: Stephen  (XYZZY)" --entitlements staticPerl.entitlements $perlEmbedRoot/bin/staticPerl5.30.0 
cp -Rp staticLib/*  $perlEmbedRoot/lib/
[lusol@Hornet:~/Private/Developer/staticPerl] dir perlembed
drwxr-xr-x   5 lusol  staff   160 Dec 15 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 lusol  staff   416 Dec 17 12:47 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 lusol  staff  6148 Dec 15 14:15 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   3 lusol  staff    96 Dec 15 14:10 bin
drwxr-xr-x  31 lusol  staff   992 Dec 10 13:47 lib
[lusol@Hornet:~/Private/Developer/staticPerl] find  perlembed 
perlembed
perlembed/.DS_Store
perlembed/bin
perlembed/bin/staticPerl5.30.0
perlembed/lib
perlembed/lib/vars.pm
perlembed/lib/FileHandle.pm
perlembed/lib/Carp.pm
```

Oh, this is the executable's path, relative to the App's Resource folder, concat together and it's suitable for a system() function, perhaps:

```
NSBundle *bund = [NSBundle mainBundle];
self.resourcePath = [bund resourcePath];
self.perlExe = @"./perlembed/bin/staticPerl5.30.0 -I./perlembed/lib/";
```

Comment: Just for clarification, could you provide your example's folder tree?